# countElements in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3, ios10

How to write this part of the code in swift 3? I am building a notes app, and this part is about a title that is going to be displayed in tableView cell

```
if countElements(item.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())) > 0


func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    //separate the body into multiple sections
    let components = self.txtBody.text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    //reset the title to blank (in case there are no components with valid text)
    self.navigationItem.title = ""
    //loop through each item in the components array (each item is auto-detected as a String)
    for item in components {
        //if the number of letters in the item (AFTER getting rid of extra white space) is greater than 0...
        if countElements(item.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())) > 0 {
            //then set the title to the item itself, and break out of the for loop
            self.navigationItem.title = item
            break 
          } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This is **not** what code comments are for. What you've essentially done is rewritten Swift code in English. But we know how to read Swift. We know what ` for item in components` means. We don't need the **how** explained in Swift and in English. What we need is the **why**. Why do you do the things that you do? What's your intent? What are you trying to achieve? **That** is what comments are for.

Comment: I wanted the first line in my textView to be displayed in the navigation bar title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
if item.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).characters.count > 0 {}
```

Comment: @JovanMilosavljevic mark it as answer if it solved your problem

Comment: `!.isEmpty` is shorter than `.characters.count > 0`:  `if !item.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty {`

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
extension String {
    func firstNonEmptyLine() -> String? {
        let lines = components(separatedBy: .newlines) 
        return lines.first(where: { 
               !$0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty })
    }
}

func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    self.navigationItem.title = self.txtBody.text.firstNonEmptyLine() ?? "Default title if there's no non-empty line"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but first answer did the job :)

Comment: This one is shorter, simpler and more general :)

Comment: `return components(separatedBy: .newlines).first{!$0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty}`

Comment: also it is better to use the newlines character set instead of `\n` and no need to trim new lines

Comment: You are supposed to return the first NOT ! isEmpty. `!$0`

Comment: @LeoDabus Fixed

Comment: @Alexander this still wrong should be `!$0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty` and just return firstToken. Or as I suggested online `return components(separatedBy: .newlines).first{!$0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty}`

Comment: you are mixing Swift 2 and 3 in your answer. `componentsSeparatedByString("\n")` is Swift 2

Comment: `components(separatedBy: .newlines)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Strange, iirc the question was original asking for Swift 2

Answer (score 0):

**Querying for the possible existence of a character that is not part of a given character set: use the right tools for the job**

> ```
> // if the number of letters in the item (AFTER getting 
> // rid of extra white space) is greater than 0...
> ```

If you simply want to know if there are any characters in the `String` instance `item` that *are not* in [`CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/characterset/1779801-whitespacesandnewlines) (a set of unicode scalars), there is no reason to use the `trimmingCharacters(in:)` method, but rather use a short-circuit approach to find the first possible unicode scalar that is not in this character set

```
if item.unicodeScalars.contains(where:
    { !CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.contains($0) }) {
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, make use of the (also short-circuiting) [`rangeOfCharacter(from:options:range:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1643031-rangeofcharacter) to find if any character can be found that is part of the inverted `.whitespaceAndNewlines` character set

```
if item.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.inverted) != nil {
    // ...
}
```